# django different interfaces for different users

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a model user2 with a one to one field with the user model,
user2 has an additional field user_type where it could be "etud", "ensg" "chef" or "tech". what I would like to do is to serve each type of users a different version of the site, currently what I'm doing is that I have everything on one page, then I check the user type for some specific HTML tags, and I'm doing this for all the site pages. so, how would I do something like that ? and is the method i'm using the best way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do.

**Rendering pages on users type based**

Let's say they land on a URL /home/, and you can map that different home page, After home_view() called.

Here you have to create generic base_home.html from this template you have to [extends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-extends) user_type specific template with the diff theme.

```
def home_view(request):
   context = {}  # add your template context here common for all user.  
   if request.user.user_type == "etud":
       # update your user_type specific context here.
       template_name = etud_home.html
       response = TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context)
       return response
   if request.user.user_type == "ensg":
       template_name = ensg_home.html
       response = TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context)
       return response
```

If you want to go with a more generic way check [process_template_response middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#process-template-response)